# How to change the color scheme of DifferentialRoot and DifferenceRoot outputs?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

**Question:**

Differential root reduce uses the font color of the stylesheet and a default white background. How to change the color of the background ?

---

**Why :**

I am using a dark style sheet where text is written in white on a black background. However, the white font and white background of the output makes it illegible like in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `DifferentialRoot` and `DifferenceRoot` use the same template for their box structure, which is named "HolonomicDisplay".

[image: HolonomicDisplay]

Therefore, the styling is set by the stylesheet, which you can access with `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "HolonomicDisplay"}]`, and also change in the usual manner of [changing stylesheet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html). You can also set it programatically:

```
displayFunction = (TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction /. 
     CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, 
       "HolonomicDisplay"}]) /. (Background -> _) -> (Background -> Yellow);

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["HolonomicDisplay"], 
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {InterpretationFunction -> (#2 &), 
        DisplayFunction -> displayFunction}]}]];
```

[image]

### Version 13.1+

It seems that `TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction` was changed to `TemplateBoxOptions` in 13.1. Therefore, you should instead use:

```
displayFunction = (TemplateBoxOptions /. 
     CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, 
       "HolonomicDisplay"}]) /. (Background -> _) -> (Background -> Yellow);
```

Comment: I wish I could press the up vote button again to give more than +1. That is an amazing answer. Lesson learned: use `ToBoxes` when you want to fiddle with Mathematica designs.

Comment: You even defined the difference root with the same y[2+n] !.

Comment: Oh, actually I just copied the first occurence of ``DifferenceRoot`` from the documentation! Didn't even notice it was the same as yours :-)

Comment: Thanks I am bad with stylesheet designing so that code is very useful to me.

Comment: I forgot to accept sorry.

Comment: Maybe the TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction /. ... at the beginning of the definition of displayFunction is supposed to be `DisplayFunction /. (TemplateBoxOptions /. 
   CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "HolonomicDisplay"}])` ?

Comment: TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction does not seem to be contained in `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "HolonomicDisplay"}]`

Comment: Alternatively `Cases[CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "HolonomicDisplay"}], HoldPattern[DisplayFunction -> s_] :> s, All][[1]]`

Comment: Thank you again. Seeing how much digging and knowledge is involved, it's astonishing that this question got an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, my code works in 12.3 and 13.0 (both Windows). Are you using some newer version (like 13.2)?

Comment: Oh you see TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction in your notebook ? I have 13.1 on Linux. Maybe they changed it there.

Comment: Yes, I do. However (as presented in the code), when _setting_ the value, I do have to use ``TemplateBoxOptions``. I guess this weird discrepancy was fixed in 13.1.